# dot used in non linear expression Julia JuMP

Tags: julia, julia-jump

getting the following error "ERROR: Unrecognized function :dot used in nonlinear expression."

```
using JuMP
m = Model()
@variable(m, 0 <= x[1:5] <=1)
@constraint(m, sum( x[i] for i=1:5) == 1)
@NLobjective(m,Max,dot(x', ex_mu) / sqrt(dot(x',S*x)))
```

ex_mu is (5x1) Float64 vector and S is (5x5) Float64 array.

Note : ' denotes transpose in my objective expression

What changes should I make to convert in into AffExpr as suggested [here](http://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nlp.html#syntax-notes) in JuMP docs or some other change is required.

Comment: Why don't you just write `x'*S*x`?